# My octave function returns "ans = 0" -Coursera Machine Learning Week 2 problem

Tags: octave

I am currently taking Andrew Nguyen's coursera machine learning course and I am on week 2. For a cost function assignment, my function keeps on returning "ans = 0" when it should be returning "ans= 32.07:
My code is below (The variables have been defined in the command window):

```
%COMPUTECOST Compute cost for linear regression
%   J = COMPUTECOST(X, y, theta) computes the cost of using theta as the
%   parameter for linear regression to fit the data points in X and y

% Initialize some useful values
% number of training examples
m = length(y);
% You need to return the following variables correctly 
J =0;

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================

% Instructions: Compute the cost of a particular choice of theta
%               You should set J to the cos
h = X * theta;
J = (1/(2m)*(sum(h-y).^2));

% =========================================================================

end
```

Comment: You’re missing a function declaration at the top of the file, I think. Please [edit] your question to include full (but minimal!) code, including how you call the function.